# Qual web service posso usar no desenvolvimento de um app?

Tags: web-service

Estou desenvolvendo um App e preciso que me indiquem qual Web Service posso usar.
Eu tenho que ter um servidor na nuvem, instalar um banco de dados nesse servidor e configurar um *web service* para ser acessado pelo iOS e Android? Como está configurado o seu *web service*?

Comment: Tente ser mais claro na sua pergunta. De uma olhada na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja como funciona o site e umas [dicas de como melhorar a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: O problema dessa pergunta é que ela é baseada em opiniões e ampla demais visto que o AP não definiu as necessidades e restrições da aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Há várias alternativas para o que você está querendo criar. A melhor recomendação dependerá do sua experiência com que sistemas operacionais e linguagens de programação.

A título de exemplo, posso citar Amazon Web Services, Heroku, Windows Azure e Google App Engine. Há muito mais alternativas, algumas mais flexíveis, outras mais simples.

Você também pode nem precisar usar uma dessas plataformas citadas. Você pode procurar empresas que ofereçam hosting de servidores (exclusivos ou compartilhados) e instalar tudo o que você precisa manualmente. Tecnicamente eles estarão na tal nuvem.